# Title, author and email flush-left alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I need to edit a document (not written by me, so I'd like to keep tinkering to a minimum), and want to left-align the title, and both authors and their details. It currently appears centred.

I've tried to modify answers to similar questions, but my modifications created errors -- one with \makeatother did *almost* align everything left, but messed up the required point sizes and line spacings.

If anyone can help, please keep it simple, I'm new to this!

```
    %\usepackage{breakcites}

    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    %\usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{latexsym}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.6in, right=1.6in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{relsize}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{appendix}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{pxfonts}
    %\usepackage{fontspec}


    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks,
        linkcolor={black!50!black},
        citecolor={black!50!black},
        urlcolor={black!50!black}
    }

    \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
    %TCIDATA{OutputFilter=LATEX.DLL}
    %TCIDATA{Version=5.50.0.2953}
    %TCIDATA{<META NAME="SaveForMode" CONTENT="1">}
    %TCIDATA{BibliographyScheme=BibTeX}
    %TCIDATA{LastRevised=Tuesday, July 21, 2015 21:10:06}
    %TCIDATA{<META NAME="GraphicsSave" CONTENT="32">}
    %TCIDATA{Language=American English}

    \doublespacing
    \newtheorem*{T1 NAME}{T1 NAME}
    \newtheorem*{T2 NAME}{T2 NAME}
    \newtheorem*{T3 NAME}{T3 NAME}
    \newtheorem{T4 NAME}{T4 NAME}
    \newtheorem*{T5 NAME}{T5 NAME}
    %\input{tcilatex}


    \begin{document}
    \title{\textbf{TITLE}}
    \author{\textsc{AUTHOR 1}\\
    \small \emph{AFFILIATION 1}\\
    \href{EMAIL 1}{\small{EMAIL 1}}\\\\
    \textsc{AUTHOR 2}\\
    \small \emph{AFFILIATION 2}\\
    \href{EMAIL 2}{\small{EMAIL 2}}}
    \date{}
    \maketitle
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: I included the earlier code in case any of it was responsible for the problem or relevant to the solution. As I said, I'm new to this, and don't know what is 'only' required.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using the `article` document class, I suggest you the `\patchcmd` macro of the `etoolbox` package to alter the behavior of the `\@maketitle` macro; the `\@maketitle` macro contains formatting instructions that are executed internally when LaTeX encounters the `\maketitle` instruction.

Simply insert the following commands towards the end of your document's preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\begin{center}}{\begin{flushleft}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\end{center}}{\end{flushleft}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

The code replaces the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` statements with `\begin{flushleft}` and `\end{flushleft}`, and it changes the column type used in the internal `tabular` environment used to typeset the `\author`-related material from `c` ("center") to `@{}l` ("absolute flush-left").

---

Here's a version of your document, with the preamble stripped down to the bare necessities for typesetting the title, author, and date blocks. Incidentally, commands such as `\small` act as switches and do not take an argument. Thus, instead of `\small{EMAIL 1}`, it would be better to write `{\small EMAIL 1}` -- the curly braces should delimite the scope of the `\small` instruction.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing
    \usepackage[vmargin=1.0in,hmargin=1.6in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{pxfonts}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks,
        linkcolor={black!50!black},
        citecolor={black!50!black},
        urlcolor ={black!50!black}
        }

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\begin{center}}{\begin{flushleft}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\end{center}}{\end{flushleft}}{}{}
\makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \title{\textbf{TITLE}}
    \author{\textsc{AUTHOR 1}\\
    \small \emph{AFFILIATION 1}\\
    \href{EMAIL 1}{\small{EMAIL 1}}\\\\
    \textsc{AUTHOR 2}\\
    \small \emph{AFFILIATION 2}\\
    \href{EMAIL 2}{\small{EMAIL 2}}}
    \date{}
    \maketitle

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Is this essentially just removing the title and author formatting tags and nailing the lines of text on by hand? This is a format I probably want to re-use often, so I wondered whether there was a way of keeping the general frame and just modifying the alignment. Or is it that just not easily doable?

Comment: @David - Thanks for this comment and for clarifying your objective. I'm posting an altered answer that patches the `\@maketitle` command, to induce flush-left instead of centered positioning of the contents of the `\title`, `\author` and `\date` macros.

Comment: @David -- Only "seems to have" done the trick? :-)